# URL Rewriting with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

if iam giving my url as http://localhost/york/aboutus.php it is working fine, but the problem i am having is that if i provide http://localhost/york/aboutus.php/ or any character after the trailing slash of the above url and then if load that page then  all the css and javascript files are not working.  Please provide me the solution to this problem.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: i'm assuming you already use url rewrite in htaccess.
RewriteRule york/aboutus.php/? york/aboutus.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the way you are including the javascript / css files in your page. With more details you will probably get a more detailed answer, but I would guess you are using .htaccess to rewrite the page in question and then in your html you are using a relative path for the src/link attributes of js/css. Every forward slash in your URL, the clients browser will assume is a directory and it will calculate relative paths accordingly.

The solution is to provide all your src/js paths relative to Root not your cwd. That is to say they should begin with a forward slash and then have the full path from your root directory. This way the clients browser will request http://www.domain.com/path/to/style.css, regardless of how many slashes are in the pages URL.